# How to send more than 25 records at once to the server using the REST API

Tags: rest-api, httprequest

I want to send (a lot more) than 25 new records to the server using the REST API to Salesforce.

**For example:**

I have a `CattleOwner` and 50 `Cattle` objects that are liked by id to the owner object.

Due to this linking and that I have to be sure, that all my records aka battles are successfully created (`allornone`-flag), I think, I have to use the `Composite Request`.

**Problem**

This kind of request is limited to just 25 records per request.

Do anybody knows another approach to be transaction save and send more than 25 records at once to the server? The `batch request` does not allow to link the objects, etc. pp. The `SObjectTree` has no `allornone`-fag, too.

Comment: Have you considered adding/using an external id on the owner to built these relationships?

Comment: @Gilhil Do you mean local at my app or in Salesforce itself?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a field on cattleowner called external_Id__c type text and check both unique and external id checkbox in salesforce.

Then on creating the cattle you can reference the cattleOwner by its external id.
for example:

```
{
    "name":"cattle1",
    "cattleOwner__r":
    {
        "unique_id__c": "myUniqueOwnerIdentifier"
    }
}
```

This will allow you to split up the call between 1 call for cattleOwners and a second call for the cattle without having to worry about the limit of 25

Comment: Thanks for this aw some tip! Nevertheless, I do not have the permission to update the salesforce object structure.